# Laravel and php best multiple search method

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have a controller that get the four inputs from a search form.

> SearchController.php code

```
public function results(Request $request) {
    $text           = $request -> text;
    $pet            = $request -> pet;
    $category       = $request -> category;
    $city           = $request -> city;
    $searchArray    = [];
    if(empty($text) && empty($pet) && empty($category) && empty($city)) {
        Session::flash('danger', "You didn't select any search any search.");
        return redirect() -> back();
    }

    //SEARCH CODE HERE
}
```

> What I am trying to do

I am trying to search 4 columns in my database

> Problem is

I need also to search the 4 columns in one query.

That means that I need to check if the `$text` variable is not empty and `$pet` variable is not empty then I have to do this query:

```
if(!empty($text) && !empty($pet))
            $result = Post::where('text', 'like', '%'.$text.'%') -> where('text', $pet) -> get();
```

This method will work fine but I will have multiple if statements that will check all the possibilities.

Is there faster and optimal solution?

Comment: See searchable package for Laravel https://github.com/nicolaslopezj/searchable you can use it with bootstrap typeahead plugin to implement a nice customizable search

Comment: @SapneshNaik it will read about it thank you :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Option 1**

Build logic manually. This is the best way in many situations. An example:

```
$result = Post::query();

if (!empty($text)) {
    $result = $result->where('text', 'like', '%'.$text.'%');
}

if (!empty($pet)) {
    $result = $result->where('pet', $pet);
}

if (!empty($category)) {
    $result = $result->where('category', $category);
}

if (!empty($city)) {
    $result = $result->where('city', 'like', '%'.$city.'%');
}

$result = $result->get();
```

**Option 2**

Use [conditional clauses](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#conditional-clauses). Example:

```
Post::when($text, function ($q) use ($text) {
        return $q->where('text', 'like', '%'.$text.'%');
    })
    ->when($pet, function ($q) use ($pet) {
        return $q->where('pet', $pet);
    })
    ->when($category, function ($q) use ($category) {
        return $q->where('category', $category);
    })
    ->when($city, function ($q) use ($city) {
        return $q->where('city', 'like', '%'.$city.'%');
    })
    ->get();
```

Comment: That's a very good solution and exactly what I am looking for.. I didn't know that I could do this in Laravel :D

Comment: The perfect solution for me :) was looking for this today.. thanks for the answer